# Cannot install .deb, applications and third party softwares

Tags: software-installation, download

so i installed on a freshly new ultrabook Asus Zenbook UX32A Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki, and tried to install Google Chrome. Downloaded from offical site, install did nothing. Tried it via terminal multiple different install commands and only errors were popping out. Then i tried to at least download LibreOffice, firstly in AppCenter, then via terminal. Both ways the same error popped out. Third party software was checked in when i was installing OS. I have two separate drives, 24GB SSD and 500GB HDD. OS was installed onto HDD not SSD. Always says some kind of error over packages. I will be really glad if someone could help me, I am a newcommer from Windows. Thanks! (Also wanted to install Gdebi, but wont let me since NO apps can be downloaded and installed) :(

Command & Error (same for every install of whatever it is):

```
nodex@nodex:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install libreoffice
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libreoffice : Depends: fonts-sil-gentium-basic but it is not installable
                   Depends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:5.1.6~rc2-0ubuntu1~xenial2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libreoffice-draw but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libreoffice-report-builder-bin but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libreoffice-writer but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: fonts-dejavu but it is not installable
                   Depends: python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: libreoffice-gnome but it is not going to be installed or
                               libreoffice-kde but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

[image]

Comment: Do you use `sudo apt-get update` and later `sudo apt-get upgrade` before trying to install software?

Comment: yes. multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing broken dependencies:
`sudo apt-get -f install`
`sudo dpkg --configure -a`
`sudo apt-get -f install`
And clean downloaded debs:
`sudo apt-get autoclean`
Now update and upgrade:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

If these steps do not work, please post the output from running:
`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`
and
`cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.

1. Press Super (Windows key) + T for terminal
2. type 'sudo dpkg -i ' and drag the file you want to install from a 'Files' window to the terminal
3. Voilá

Another possibility: simply install the elementary OS .deb installer called Eddy from the AppCenter.

Comment: Hello Dan, problem is that app center helds like only apps that are installed into the system by default and nothing else. But i will try it, althought $ sudo dpkg -i doesnt work at all, tried that aswell.

Comment: Hmm, wierd, today I installed Chrome, LibreOffice SimpleNote with sudo dpkg -i '~/Downloads/Chrome.deb'